# WebForm wait for user to finish typing in a Text Box

Tags: c#, webforms, textbox

There is a webform with search textbox(txtSearch) and list usercontrol(lstItem).
user type text on txtSearch and on serverside textchanged event lstitem created and show to user.
I have 2 problem:

1- Normally, event X is called by typing each character. But it is desirable that the event be called after the user stops typing.

Comment: 1, choose which problem you want us to answer - SO is "one problem per question". 2, post more detail, including code etc

Comment: The first problem is more important than the second problem

Comment: K, so remove the second question and post some code for the first

Comment: How do you know that a user stopped typing? How long should it take me to fill in your text box? What if it takes me longer? What if I fill it in faster?  You may consider if using  `onfocusout` or `onblur` meets your needs.

Comment: for examples can we can set 1 second or 500 milisecond and etc. for winform you can user timer and for wpf there is delay att for textview.... @user9938

Comment: there are not special code, it's simple webform page with listbox and textbox @CaiusJard

Comment: No one wants to wait for a set amount of time to expire. Use a button.

Comment: Thanks, it's our business and need it,If you can, provide a solution for our problem. @user9938

Comment: Provide the code that you are currently using or a small demo project that demonstrates how you are currently accomplishing it.

Comment: And for web there is javascript setinterval etc

Comment: I think this will do everything you want. http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx.  You can add the Ajaxtoolkit to you application from NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I handled delay by keypress and Used RadAjaxManager

UI Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        var clientId = '<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>';
        var myVar = null;
        $('#' + clientId).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.key == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            clearTimeout(myVar);
            var txt = $(this).val();
            myVar = setTimeout(function () {
                var val = $('#' + clientId).val();
                FillListCustomProperties<%= this.ClientID %>(val);
            }, 500);
        })
    });

    function FillListCustomProperties<%= this.ClientID %>(txt) {
        debugger;
        var ajaxManager = 'searchproperties_' + '<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>';
        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>").ajaxRequest(ajaxManager);
    }
</script>


<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="id" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="AjaxRequestEvent">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Id">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="myControlId" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Back Code :

```
private void AjaxRequestEvent(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Argument))
    {
        if (e.Argument.StartsWith("searchproperties"))
        {
            if (e.Argument.Contains(txtSearch.ClientID))
            {
                FillList(txtSearch.Text);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```